# Save cart through backend gives @return type error

Tags: magento2.3, interceptor

I am trying to change some data on a cart through the backend programmatically, i have a grid with a few actions, if i execute the Approve or Reject action it will go to a GET url.

**Admin Controller**

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Blabla\CustomerBalance\Controller\Adminhtml\Cart;

// Uses

class Authorize extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    // Code...

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    public function execute(): ResponseInterface
    {
        $companyId      = (int) $this->_request->getParam('company');
        $cartId         = (int) $this->_request->getParam('cart');
        $action         = $this->_request->getParam('status');
        $status         = (int) $this->getAuthorizationStatus($action);
        $authorizerName = $this->adminSession->getName() . ' (Customer Service)';

        try {
            $cart = $this->cartManagement->authorize($cartId, $status, $authorizerName);

            // Code...
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Add message for the customer.
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('Something went wrong while approving/rejecting the cart. Error: %1', $e->getMessage())
            );

            // Log error message.
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this->_redirect('company/index/edit', ['id' => $companyId]);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```php
<?php

namespace Blabla\CustomerBalance\Model;

// Uses

/**
 * Class CartManagement
 *
 * @package Blabla\CustomerBalance\Model
 */
class CartManagement implements CartManagementInterface
{
    // ...

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function authorize(int $cartId, int $status, string $authorizerName, string $reason = '')
    {
        // Get the cart.
        $cart = $this->cartRepository->get($cartId);

        // Some code...

        // Save the cart.
        $this->cartRepository->save($cart);

        return $cart;
    }
}
```

The cart cant be saved because i get the following error:

> Method's return type must be specified using @return annotation. See Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer\Interceptor::setData()

**Interceptor**

```php
<?php
namespace Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer;

/**
 * Interceptor class for @see \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer
 */
class Interceptor extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer implements \Magento\Framework\Interception\InterceptorInterface
{
    // Code ...

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setData($key, $value)
    {
        $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'setData');
        if (!$pluginInfo) {
            return parent::setData($key, $value);
        } else {
            return $this->___callPlugins('setData', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
        }
    }

    // Code ...
}
```

If i change the DocBlocks of the `SetData` method to:

```
/**
 * @param string $key
 * @param mixed  $value
 *
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer|mixed|null
 */
```

The code will be executed without problems... i just can't figure out how to fix this, anyone can lead me in to the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After heavily debugging and searching on the web i have found a solution.

The exception is getting triggered in `vendor/magento/module-customer-segment/Observer/ProcessQuoteObserver.php`.

By replacing line 59:

```php
'data' => $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter->toFlatArray($customerData),
```

with:

```php
'data' => $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter->toFlatArray($customerData, [], \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::class),
```

Will fix the exception and continue the save of the cart.

Comment: saved my day, tho customer segment should be an enterprise module and so addressed by commercial support

Comment: Saved My Day! Thank you!